# NullPointerException when setting attribute?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

For example I have a servlet code that sets attribute to a HttpServletRequest:

```
request.setAttribute("someValue", someValue());
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SomeJsp.jsp");
        rd.forward(this.request, this.response);
        return;
```

How do I make sure that the code above is thread safe?

This is the stacktrace I am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1552)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.access$000(Request.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request$3.set(Request.java:3342)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1504)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.servlet.SomeServlet.doRequest(SomeServlet.java:103)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.servlet.SomeServlet.doGet(SomeServlet.java:159)
```

Comment: your request object is null

Comment: what is `someValue()`? is it possible that it returns `null`?

Comment: Check if someValue() is null

Comment: Looks like an internal error (setting an attribute to `null` is not a problem, but something inside of `forward` crashes). There is something weird happening with your ServletRequest.

Comment: you might forgot to use getSession() aswell??

Comment: Does the somevalue() should avoid the function , use some variable as somevalue,[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: "There is something weird happening with your ServletRequest." Indeed. And @BalusC has the explanation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
rd.forward(this.request, this.response);
```

This (pun intented) suggests that you've assigned `request` and `response` as instance variables of a class. Your concrete problem in turn suggests that the instance of the class itself is not threadsafe.

Assuming that it's actually the servlet itself, then you've there the cause of your problem. Servlets are not threadsafe at all. There's only one instance of it been created during webapp's startup which is then shared across *all* requests applicationwide.

You should **never** assign request or session scoped data as an instance variable of the servlet. It would only be overriden whenever another HTTP request takes place at the same moment. That would make your code threadunsafe, as you encountered yourself.

Here's some code which illustrates that:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Object thisIsNOTThreadSafe;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Object thisIsThreadSafe;

        thisIsNOTThreadSafe = request.getParameter("foo"); // BAD!! Shared among all requests!
        thisIsThreadSafe = request.getParameter("foo"); // OK, this is thread safe.
    } 
}
```

Assigning the HTTP request itself as instance variable of a servlet is actually an epic mistake. When user Y fires another request at the same time the servlet is dealing with the request of user X, then user X would instantly get the `request` and `response` objects of user Y at hands. This is definitely threadunsafe. The NPE is caused because the `request` is at that moment "finished" with processing for user Y and thus released/destroyed.

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

Comment: +1. I'd say your right on the money. Totally missed the `this.request` nonsense. That would explain it.

Comment: @balasC I have same issue, Can you please review It 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044187/struts2-execandwait-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 2):

Request is thread safe by it's definition (unlike Session and ServletContext).

Regarding the exception: what Tomcat version are you using? This looks like a Tomcat bug.

Does the class that is the return type of `someValue()` method implement `HttpAttributeBindingListener`? And, can `someValue()` method return `null`? If both yes then the `NullPointerException` is obvious.

Comment: Obvious? Really? How could a value be both `null` and implement something?

Comment: The container expects a value of some type which may implement `ServletRequestAttributeListener`. And if an attribute does implement this interface then right after the attribute is attached to the request `ServletRequestAttributeListener.attributeAdded(...)` or `ServletRequestAttributeListener.attributeReplace(...)` called by the container.

Comment: Setting `null` as attribute value is absolutely legit. So your "is obvious" argument has totally no grounds. As to the possible Tomcat bug, look in Tomcat source code before making such a dangerous statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this has to do with it being thread safe.

The exception you're getting is a NullPointerException it looks like Tomcat is trying to invoke a method on a null object.

In a Java web application each request has its own HttpServletRequest instance, so you can set the attributes on the request and be confident it is only for that user.

Comment: It's not his code trying to invoke a method on a null object, it's Tomcat internals.

Comment: If you have explored Tomcat's source code then you'd have noticed that the method is trying to access a variable which was been released long before by end of HTTP request processing. This in turn suggests that another thread has released it and thus definitely a thread safety problem.

Answer (score 1):

use without this operator

```
     RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SomeJsp.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at implementaion of request interface in tomcat it looks like below code.

```
public void setAttribute(String name, Object value) {

    // Name cannot be null
    if (name == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
            (sm.getString("coyoteRequest.setAttribute.namenull"));

    // Null value is the same as removeAttribute()
    if (value == null) {
        removeAttribute(name);
        return;
    }

    if (name.equals(Globals.DISPATCHER_TYPE_ATTR)) {
        internalDispatcherType = (DispatcherType)value;
        return;
    } else if (name.equals(Globals.DISPATCHER_REQUEST_PATH_ATTR)) {
        requestDispatcherPath = value;
        return;
    }
```

Its clearly seen that if key is null then it throw **IllegalArgumentException** but if value is **null** then it simply remove the key and old associated object with that key from reposatory. But if none of them is **null** them it will associate the object with that key and add them o repository.

It seems a temporary or tomcat issue.

for more on implementation refer to below link 
[Source code of Request Implementation by tomcat](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/connector/Request.java/?v=source)

Comment: "It seems a temporary or tomcat issue." Or the problem described by @BalusC.